# AWS cognito with serverless framework

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, amazon-cognito

I am working on serverless framework. For user authentication I am using aws cognito and I want to create api using lambda function for sign-up user,Authenticate users,change password etc..Is it possible using serverless framework.

if possible please suggest any example.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html

Comment: Be aware Cognito is great for simple applications but has some serious limitations, last time I checked you can't search via custom attributes in a user pool. Generally most people will write their own sign up/sign in logic and issue a jwt token. An example of a custom authorizer can be found here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/nodejs/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created it. You can find it here: 
https://github.com/awslabs/cognito-proxy-rest-service

BTW, the question to ask yourself is why you need to push down the auth logic to the backend when Cognito has everything you need to work with it on the front-end?

Comment: By using aws cognito I have to fully depend on aws if I will write auth logic to front end and if  in future I wants to change my auth logic then I have to again modify my front end part

Comment: You have created lambda fun in kotlin.Do you have same in nodejs?

Comment: No, just Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. To achieve this, basically you need to wrap [Cognito API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html) at your own Lambda functions and then configure [http event](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#simple-http-endpoint) for them at your serverless framework template.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider that Cognito is Backend as a Service (BaaS) for authentication and it exposes APIs for using it. So you can use AWS SDKs in order to access these APIs. However you can write your own Lambda function (serverless application), using Serverless Framework Toolkit, in order to access Cognito. You can find more information about integrating Cognito in either Mobile- or Web-application using Javascript SDK [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-sdk-links.html). Also you can find more information about AWS SDk in other languages [here](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk).